# "Object throwing attribute error for _sa_instance_state in Python FastAPI "

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am using logging in Python to show in the console when the dates when the user creates a user or query in the end_point, I want to get all the object by using logger.error(f"User already registered {db_user.**dict**}"), and I am getting this error when creating a user as below.

User created successfully {'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f7b40be49a0>}

This is in FastAPI
.
My code is below

@router.post("/users", response_model=UserDTO)

async def create_user(
response: Response, user: UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):

```
db_user = user_crud.check_if_user_exists(db=db, user=user)
if db_user:
    logger.error(f"User already registered {db_user.__dict__}")
    logger.error(format_exc(limit=1))
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail="User already registered"
    )
new_user = user_crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)

if new_user:
    logger.info(f"User created successfully {new_user.__dict__}")
    response.status_code = status.HTTP_201_CREATED
else:
    logger.error("Internal server error")
    logger.error(format_exc(limit=1))
    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
return new_user
```

The error message:

It creates creates the user but does not show in the console the user which was created, and show the memory address.

User created successfully {'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f7b40be49a0>}

Any idea how to get to get the created user ?

Comment: what is `user_crud`? can you share code of `create_user` method?

Comment: def create_user(db: Session, user:UserCreate) -> User:
    db_user = User(
        first_name=user.first_name,
        last_name=user.last_name,
        email=user.email,
        password=user.password,
    )

    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()

    return db_user